# I want to allow a live stream to be started by a 1.5 second long tap, but my code requires users to hold down the button the entire stream

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I need to allow users to begin live streaming video to their friends by pressing an additionalCameraButton for ~1.5 seconds. However currently they have to hold it down the entire time, and the moment they remove their finger from the additionalCameraButton, the cameraView is cancelled.

I'm working with someone's old code that I just converted from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3 and I see what they did, but when I alter it slightly to get the minimumDuration for the longTap gesture, I get fatal errors.

How would any of you go about altering the code to allow for a 1.5 second longTap instead of having to hold it down indefinitely? On line 58 I have the code to add the minimumDuration for the longTap but adding it causes all sorts of errors as upon letting go of the button, the cameraView is still canceled even though the live stream has started.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

protocol CameraViewDelegate {
func startStopRecordingVideo(_ isStart: Bool)
func startStopStream(_ isStart: Bool)
func cancelCameraView()
func changeCamera()
func chooseVideo()
}

class CameraView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var flashBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var screenView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var shootBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var changeCameraBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var cancelBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var alphaView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var shootBtnContainerView: UIView!

var delegate : CameraViewDelegate?
var isRecording : Bool = false
var isStreaming: Bool = false

var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer?
var timer: Timer?

//MARK: SYSTEMS METHODS

class func instanceFromNib() -> CameraView {
    return UINib(nibName: "View", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil,     options: nil)[0] as! CameraView
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    layoutIfNeeded()
    shootBtnContainerView.layer.cornerRadius =     shootBtnContainerView.frame.size.width/2
    shootBtn.layer.cornerRadius = shootBtn.frame.size.width/2

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    shootBtn.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    let hideTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideTapped))
    hideTap.delegate = self
    alphaView.addGestureRecognizer(hideTap)

    let hold = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longTap))
    shootBtn.addGestureRecognizer(hold)
    //hold.minimumPressDuration = 1.5

    if Defaults.sharedDefaults.userKnowAboutCamera {
        alphaView.isHidden = true
    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Testing!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Thank You", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)

}

//MARK: - CIRcLE ANIMATION

func createCirclePath() {
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: shootBtnContainerView.center, radius: shootBtnContainerView.frame.size.width/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(.pi * 2.0), clockwise: true)

    circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer!.path = circlePath.cgPath
    circleLayer!.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circleLayer!.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    circleLayer!.lineWidth = 3.0;

    circleLayer!.strokeEnd = 0.0

    layer.addSublayer(circleLayer!)
}

func animateCircle(_ duration: TimeInterval) {
    circleLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    createCirclePath()
    circleLayer!.strokeEnd = 0.0
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.duration = duration
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    circleLayer!.strokeEnd = 1.0
    circleLayer!.add(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
}


// SHOW HIDE ALPHA VIEW

func showHideAlphaView(_ isHide: Bool){
    Defaults.sharedDefaults.userKnowAboutCamera = true
    var alpha: Float = 0.0
    if isHide { alpha = 0.0 } else { alpha = 0.6 }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
        self.alphaView.alpha = CGFloat(alpha)
        }, completion: nil)
}

// ACTIONS

func hideTapped(){
    showHideAlphaView(true)
}

func doubleTapped() {
    delegate?.chooseVideo()
}

func longTap(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tapping")
    if sender.state == .began {
        SSContact.shared.isStreaming(public: true, to: nil, verification: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }, live: { (live, views) in
            print("Live: \(live) :: With \(views) Views!")
        })
        isRecording = !isRecording
        delegate?.startStopRecordingVideo(isRecording)
        isStreaming = !isStreaming
        delegate?.startStopStream(isStreaming)
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        SSContact.shared.stopStreaming()
        isRecording = !isRecording
        delegate?.startStopRecordingVideo(isRecording)
        isStreaming = !isStreaming
        delegate?.startStopStream(isStreaming)
        delegate?.cancelCameraView()
    }
}

func updateTimer() {
    isRecording = !isRecording
    delegate?.startStopRecordingVideo(isRecording)
    timer?.invalidate()
}

@IBAction func shootVideo(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if !isRecording{
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 20.0, target: self, selector: #selector(CameraView.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        animateCircle(20)
    } else {
        timer?.invalidate()
        circleLayer?.removeAnimation(forKey: "animateCircle")
        circleLayer!.strokeEnd = 0.0
    }
    isRecording = !isRecording
    delegate?.startStopRecordingVideo(isRecording)
}

@IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.cancelCameraView()
}

@IBAction func changeCameraPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.changeCamera()
}

@IBAction func flashBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)!
    if (device.hasTorch) {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            if device.torchMode == .on {
                device.torchMode = .off
                flashBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Flash"), for: UIControlState())
            } else {
                flashBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "NoFlash"), for: UIControlState())
                do {
                    try device.setTorchModeOnWithLevel(1.0)
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func loadVideoPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

}
}
```

Comment: Look at your `longTap` method for the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, you say `if sender.state == .ended` to basically stop streaming, so whenever the user releases the touch it will stop:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your `longTap` method for the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, you say `if sender.state == .ended` to basically stop streaming, so whenever the user releases the touch it will stop:

```
func longTap(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .began {
        // Start the stream
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        SSContact.shared.stopStreaming()
        isRecording = !isRecording
        delegate?.startStopRecordingVideo(isRecording)
        isStreaming = !isStreaming
        delegate?.startStopStream(isStreaming)
        delegate?.cancelCameraView()
    }

}
```

I would suggest maybe having a method that manages starting and stopping the stream based on your `isRecording` boolean, and changing the way `isRecording` is declared to use a `didSet`:

```
var isRecording: Bool = false {
    didSet{
        // Manage the stream based on how the variable is set
        self.manageStream(start: isRecording)
    }
}


func manageStream(start: Bool) {

    if start {
        // Start the stream
        SSContact.shared.isStreaming(public: true, to: nil, verification: { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }, live: { (live, views) in
            print("Live: \(live) :: With \(views) Views!")
        })
        isRecording = !isRecording
        delegate?.startStopRecordingVideo(isRecording)
        isStreaming = !isStreaming
        delegate?.startStopStream(isStreaming)
    }
    else {
        // Stop the stream
        SSContact.shared.stopStreaming()
        isRecording = !isRecording
        delegate?.startStopRecordingVideo(isRecording)
        isStreaming = !isStreaming
        delegate?.startStopStream(isStreaming)
        delegate?.cancelCameraView()
    }

}
```

Now you can use the longPress recognizer to start and stop the streaming :

```
func longTap(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    isRecording = !isRecording

}
```

You could even change the duration of the press, like say you wanted the minimum press duration to be much less to turn the stream off as opposed to turning it on:

```
func longTap(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    isRecording = !isRecording
    if isRecording {
        // Make the minimum duration zero so they just need to tap to turn it off
        sender.minimumPressDuration = 0
    } else {
        // Make the minimum duration back to 1.5 seconds so they have to hold to turn it on
        sender.minimumPressDuration = 1.5
    }

}
```

Comment: I got it working! Had to make slight adjustments to the code to fit everything but it's smooth as a whistle now. Thanks!

Comment: @JustinHodges - Sure thing! Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Your `UILongPressGestureRegonizer`s target is `longTap(_:)`. This method will be executed whenever the gesture recognizer fires an event. Lets look your implementation of this method then:

```
func longTap(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tapping")
    if sender.state == .began {
        // ...
        delegate?.startStopStream(isStreaming)
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        SSContact.shared.stopStreaming()
        // ...
    }
}
```

I replaced some code with `// ...` to focus on what matters here. As you can see, a `UILongPressGestureReconizer` can have multiple states (also see the [API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizerstate)). In your code you are handling two of them: `.began` and `.ended`.

The gesture recognizers state will be `.began` once your gesture has been recognized (ie. the long press has been executed by the user). In this `if` branch you are starting your camera recording and also your stream. In your `.ended` branch on the other hand you are stopping your stream. The state will be `.ended` when the gesture ends (ie. when the user lifts his finger, as the long press has now ended).

If you want the stream to continue after the long press, simple remove the `.ended` branch.